# c# Display data from database in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to insert image into sql server and then I want to render back in datagridview in c#.I got this codes from internet. I've following database schemes

```
create table product
 (
   product_id int not null primary key identity,
   product_serialno varchar(10) not null unique,
   product_name varchar(60) not null,
   brand_id int,
   category_id int,
   img varbinary,
   remarks text
  )
```

I've used following code for insertion

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Picture.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] pic_arr = new byte[ms.Length];

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["conSetting"]);
 String sql = "Insert into product(product_serialno,product_name,brand_id,category_id,img,remarks) values(@product_serialno,@product_name,@brand_id,@category_id,@img,@remarks)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_serialno",txtProductSerial.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_name",txtProductName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brand_id",txtbrand.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category_id",txtcategory.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img",pic_arr);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks",txtRemarks.Text);

try
{
    con.Open();
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Enter all required field", "Error !!");
}finally
{
    con.Close();
    reset();
}
```

Now I've tried to display it in datagridview using following code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["conSetting"]);
String sql = "Select * From product";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
SqlDataReader dataReader;

try
{
    con.Open();
    dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    try
    {
       while (dataReader.Read())
       {
           byte[] img= (byte[])dataReader.GetValue(5);
           MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);

           //dataGridView1.
           dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dataReader[0].ToString(), dataReader[1].ToString(), dataReader[2].ToString(), dataReader[3].ToString(), dataReader[4].ToString(), Image.FromStream(ms), dataReader[6].ToString());                    
         }
     }catch(Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(),"Exception");
     }
}catch (Exception ex){  
}finally{
         con.Close();
}
```

I'm getting error in rendering image. It will be nice if anyone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some steps when you write your image to the database

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Picture.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

// Reposition the Memory stream to the beginning of the data
ms.Seek (0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

// Allocate the array
byte[] pic_arr = new byte[ms.Length];

// Read the bytes into the array
ms.Read (pic_arr, 0, ms.Length);
```

Now your array contains the effective bytes to be written to the database.

I also suggest you to not use AddWithValue but use the more precise Add with the specific datatype for the parameters. While convenient AddWithValue is [well known to be source of bugs and underperformances](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) for your database engine

Comment: I'm not getting it. Can you format it with above code

Comment: The code above goes in the Insertion phase of your code. Before opening and running the ADO.NET code. If you don't fill the pic_arr with the bytes loaded in the MemoryStream you are not writing it in the database table. (And of course you cannot read it back)